# Display minuten from TimeStamp (React, TimeStamp, Firestore)

Tags: reactjs, date, timestamp, localdate, timestamp-with-timezone

I got issue with render correct format for `Firestore TimeStamp`.

I got date:

```
<p>{data.visitAt.toString()}<p>
```

value has format: `Timestamp(seconds=1608276600, nanoseconds=0)`

Next I did:

```
render(){

        const optionsdate = {
            year: "numeric",
            month: "long",
            day: "numeric",
            hour: "numeric",
            minutes: "numeric"
        };

return(
   <div>
     <label>{data.visitAt.toDate().toLocaleDateString("en", optionsdate)}&nbsp;</label>
   </div>
)
```

But I'm getting only:

```
December 18, 2020, 8 AM
```

How to display `minutes` as well? (minuten not working)

Comment: created a sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-pike-ynqx0?file=/src/App.js - Is this are you expecting ?

Comment: exactly, thanks so much! if did as normal answer then I can accept it

Comment: sure will do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach,

```
{new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", options).format(data.visitAt.toDate())}
```

Complete code:-

```
export default function App() {
  const options = {
    year: "numeric",
    month: "numeric",
    day: "numeric",
    hour: "numeric",
    minute: "numeric",
    second: "numeric"
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {/* 3/31/2020, 1:11:51 PM */}
      <h2>{new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", options).format(1585640511000)}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codebase - https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-pike-ynqx0?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thanks, the first approach working as well, only one change: `data.visitAt.toDate()`

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer, It will be useful for others facing the same issue :)